# Is there a way to route different levels of subdomains on Route53 with wildcards?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

Is there a way to route all first level subdomains (e.g. `*.example.com`) to one IP address, and then route all second level subdomains (e.g. `*.*.example.com`) to a different IP address?

We currently use Amazon's Route53.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Route 53 interprets `*` as a wildcard only when it is alone as the leftmost token.  `*.example.com` in Route 53 matches any number of values to the left, e.g. `foo.example.com` and `bar.foo.example.com` and `quux.bar.foo.example.com`.

Route 53 won't interpret a `*` in any other circumstance as a wildcard, so there's no way to configure differing behavior based on the number of tokens.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DomainNameFormat.html#domain-name-format-asterisk